# How to redirect URL while maintaining all GET parameters using express / Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, get, redirect

Using Express/Node.js I receive GET requests with an unknown number of parameters. The names of parameters are not always known in advance. I need to redirect these requests to a new URL while maintaining all existing GET parameters.

ie. I might get any of these

```
http://example.com/example
http://example.com/example?id=xxx
http://example.com/example?a=xxx&_b=xxx...
etc
```

which in turn need to be redirected to:

```
http://newexample.com/example
http://otherdomain.org/sample?type=new&id=xxx
http://newexample.com/sample?a=xxx&_b=xxx...
etc
```

I've written this code to achieve this, but it feels like this would be common functionality that would already exist in the framework. Is there a better way?

```
app.get('/example', function(req, res){
    var oldParams = ""
    var redirectUrl = config.exampleUrlNew;
    if (req.originalUrl != null && req.originalUrl.indexOf('?') > 0) {
      oldParams = req.originalUrl.split("?")[1];
    }
    if (oldParams != "" && redirectUrl.indexOf('?') > 0) {
      oldParams = "&" + oldParams;
    } else {
      oldParams = "?" + oldParams;
    }
    res.redirect(redirectUrl + oldParams)
});
```

Comment: `req.url.replace('example.com','newexample.com')`

Comment: Fair enough... however I simplified the actual example for clarity. The replacement url is completely different vs. the original and unknown in advance (specified in configuration). It may even (likely) have hardcoded new URL parameters that were not in the original URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [`url`](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html) module

```
var URL = require('url');

var newUrl = URL.parse(oldUrl, true); // true to parse the queryString as well

newUrl.host = null; // because
newUrl.hostname = 'newexample.com';

newUrl.search = null; // because
newUrl.query.newParam = 'value';

newUrl = URL.format(newUrl);
```

There's a quirk that you have to set `.host` property to null for `.hostname` property to take precedence, because acc to the docs setting the `hostname` only works if the `host` isn't present, which it is since it's parsed from oldUrl. Ditto for `.search` and `.query`

Comment: ```URL.format()``` is deprecated.